# The scope and on-topic tags should be synonyms

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

On [Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/) the [off-topic](/questions/tagged/off-topic) and [on-topic](/questions/tagged/on-topic) meta tags are synonyms of the [scope](/questions/tagged/scope) tag.  I propose we merge our [on-topic](/questions/tagged/on-topic) meta tag into [scope](/questions/tagged/scope).

I'm not sure if this should be tagged as [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) or [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request).

Comment: [meta-tag:feature-request] is intended to request features for the core Stack Exchange software itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I must admit, that thought had occurred to me but I'd done nothing about it.

Synonym now created.